# How to ignore some folders when creating a TAR file in Linux?

Tags: linux, tar

I have a folder with 85 subfolders. I want to make a customized `.tar` file, meaning that I want to ignore some folders.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways, check these options in the doc.:

```
--exclude=PATTERN'
     When performing operations, `tar' will skip files that match
     PATTERN.  *Note exclude::.
`--exclude-from=FILE'
`-X FILE'
     Similar to `--exclude', except `tar' will use the list of patterns
     in the file FILE.  *Note exclude::.
```